# Не выводит оклад из заданной таблицы в созданную колонку, неправильный SELECT И WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

В словаре "Должности" нужно добавить дополнительную колонку "Оклад должности". Значение этого поля брать из поля "Сумма" из таблицы ФОТ "оклад" ,и всё это должно быть на действующую на системную дату(нынешнею)

***ЧТО ЕСТЬ В НАЛИЧИИ***

Есть словарь `"Должности"(DOLJNOSTI)`,в который нужно добавить поле `Сумму(SUMM)` из таблицы `DOLJNOSTFOT(Должности(фонд оплаты труда))`.
Также есть в наличии таблица `OKLZP(Состав ФОТ.)`, где в поле `NAME` надо выбрать значение '1.оклад' и выводить именно те суммы, которые относятся именно к значению `NAME='1.оклад'`.

Функция скомпилировалась, но ничего не показывает, хотя в значении SUMM нули. Хотя в таблице есть 0.
В коде представленном ниже, я пытаюсь найти номер записи`(RN)` таблица `"Должности (фонд оплаты труда)"`,с заданным условием что его номера записи совпадают с таблицей `'Должности'` и соответствует имени `'1.оклад'`

***КОД ФУНКЦИИ:***

```
create or replace function view_oklad
(
NRN NUMBER
) 
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  INRN NUMBER;
  NUMVAL NUMBER; --- переменная для отбора значений и возвращения из фукнции
BEGIN
  INRN:=NRN;
  BEGIN 
    SELECT DJLNFOT.SUMM INTO NUMVAL 
    FROM 
    DOLJNOSTFOT DJLNFOT, --- таблица "Должности (фонд оплаты труда)"
    DOLJNOSTI DJLN, --- таблица "Должности"    
    OKLZP OKL, --- таблица "Состав ФОТ", откуда берём точное название вида заработной платы(оклад)
    SHTATNDOLJN  SHTDJLN ---таблица "штатные должности", откуда надо взять Дата с(DO_ACT_FROM) и Дата по(DO_ACT_TO) для получения системной даты
    WHERE
    DJLN.RN= INRN 
    AND DJLN.RN=DJLNFOT.RN
    AND OKL.NAME='1. оклад'
    AND SHTDJLN.DO_ACT_FROM<=SYSDATE AND (SHTDJLN.DO_ACT_FROM>SYSDATE OR SHTDJLN.DO_ACT_TO IS NULL); ---сравнение системной(текущей даты)
  END;
  return NUMVAL;
end view_oklad;
```

**Что я не понимаю и почему прошу помощи или объяснения?**
Помочь понять мою ошибку при составлении запроса и условий. Все таблицы, которые я перечислил связаны между собой через номер записи `RN`

Функция компилируется, сообщений об ошибок нет. Колонка создаётся, но самих значений в поле нет.
Вполне возможно, что я неправильно пишу `SELECT` или сами условия после `WHERE`.

Если информации недостаточно, то я обновлю свой вопрос.

Comment: А где вы эту функцию вызываете ?

Comment: @Mike,в  программе Парус на учебной базе

Comment: Это конечно глупый вопрос, но всё же задам. Не опечатались ли в запросе `AND OKL.NAME='1. оклад'` - с пробелом, а в вопросе слитно